# Server Side push notifications

Tags: android, service, notifications

I am in the planning stage of creating an Android application. There will be 2 different applications for the "buyer" and "seller". I'm unsure as to how I will handle notifications. The seller will place a ticket up for sale which will then be sent to the server. The server will then send a notification to the respective buyer apps that they can buy this ticket. Once the buyer has said they will buy the ticket I want the server to then send a notification to the seller app saying that it was bought.

The issue is I'm not sure how the server is going to push these notifications to the devices. Should I just have the devices constantly sending requests to query the database to see if anything has changed? If it is possible to use a server side application for this what are some options for programming language and ways to go about accomplishing the tasks I need to be done.

So in short I need a server side application that handles sending notifications to devices. What are some possible languages and methods of handling this kind of task?

Comment: I'm currently looking into parse.com myself, think it is well worth a look. Can handle both storage and push notifications but do not know that much about it, as I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have server send messages to Android device using GCM (Google Cloud Messaging). The server can use either php or jsp implementation of web pages which the buyer or seller Android device can access.